# C# DbCommand in a loop

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I have a collection of files, for each file I am going to call an SP using Dbcommand in a transaction.

for example:

```
  DbCommand insert = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Insert");
  db.AddInParameter(insert, "FileName", System.Data.DbType.String, 
      ID + ".xml");
  db.ExecuteNonQuery(insert, transaction);
```

My question is how do I put this in a loop?

The answer below doesn't work, but thanks for the otherwise great code sample. Problem is db doesn't have a Parameters collection that you can manipulate. check...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data.sql.sqldatabase_members%28BTS.10%29.aspx

I am declaring my database like this:

```
SqlDatabase db = new SqlDatabase(this.ConnectionString );
```

Comment: What C# type is the collection of files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DbCommand insert = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Insert");
foreach (string ID in myIDs)
{
    insert.Parameters.Clear();
    db.AddInParameter(insert, "FileName", System.Data.DbType.String, 
        ID + ".xml");
    db.ExecuteNonQuery(insert, transaction);
}
```

You could also just add the Parameter once outside the loop, and then change its Value inside the loop.  Half of one, six dozen of the other.

Comment: Is someone actually downvoting this?

Comment: Just a note - the parameters need to be cleared on the DbCommand, answer updated, rest looks good, thanks

Comment: @JL: I wasn't sure what classes you were using in your sample - I usually use the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace. I'd never seen an "AddInParameter" method on anything before.

Comment: Cool stuff, good guess :) and who ever downvoted, no reason to downvote, the code works!

Comment: This might work but the performance will get much worse as the number of files goes up. Once you find you have performance problems, take a look at Erich's answer

Answer (score 3):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 (many aren't yet...) you can use table variables!  Check out: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=168

That way, you can do the entire set of files in 1 command, saving a bunch of time.

Alternatively, you could join all of the file names with a separator character, then split them on the SQL stored procedure.

The advantage is you minimize the transactions to the DB, the downside is the programming isn't as straight forward.

Comment: okay, this is just awesome.  I have several apps which would immediately benefit from this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "xxx", DbType.Int32);
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "xxx", DbType.Int32);
db.AddInParameter(cmd, "xxx", DbType.Int32);
int id = 0;
db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "ccc", DbType.Int32, id);

foreach (xxx item in xxxx)
{
    db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "xxx", item.InvestmentProgramId);
    db.SetParameterValue(cmd, "xxx", item.CompanyId);
    db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
    id = (int)db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "ccc");
    item.Id = id;
}
```